AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'icon_url'
guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
       
thumbnail = guild.icon_url if guild.icon_url else None

Error:
thumbnail = guild.icon_url if guild.icon_url else None
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'icon_url'
Im trying to get guild icon url but i cant

You have not provided a minimal block of code that reproduces the error.   no one can see what the function called does, etc.

thumbnail = guild.icon.url if guild.icon else None

